# AdMob ads are not displaying after I published my Unity game on the Google Play Console

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, admob, google-play-console

I published my game on Google Play two weeks ago, and I received a warning stating, "This SDK version has been reported as outdated. Consider upgrading to a newer version (1.1.0+)."

I released a new update for the game three days ago to address the warning.
However, AdMob ads are still not appearing.
My AdMob account is approved, the app on AdMob is ready to serve, and the units are active, but no ads are showing.

Any assistance regarding this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my script for the ads integration:

```
using System.Collections;
using GoogleMobileAds;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class AdMobAdScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private ObstacleCollision obstacleCollision;
    public AudioSource BGMFX;
    public AudioSource MenuBTnsFX;
    //public TextMeshProUGUI CoinsText;

    public TextMeshProUGUI totalCoinsTxt;
    public string appId = "My App ID";

#if UNITY_ANDROID
    string bannerId = "My Admob Banner ID";
    string interId = "My Admob Interstitial ID";
    string rewardedId = "My Admob Rewarded ID";
#else
    string bannerId = "unused";
    string interId = "unused";
    string rewardedId = "unused";
#endif

    BannerView bannerView;
    InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
    RewardedAd rewardedAd;


    private void Start()
    {
        
        MobileAds.RaiseAdEventsOnUnityMainThread = true;
        MobileAds.Initialize(initStatus => {

            print("Ads Initialised !!");

        });

        ShowCoins();
        LoadBannerAd();
        LoadInterstitialAd();
        LoadRewardedAd();
        
    }


    #region Banner

    public void LoadBannerAd()
    {
        //create a banner
        CreateBannerView();

        //listen to banner events
        ListenToBannerEvents();

        //load the banner
        if (bannerView == null)
        {
            CreateBannerView();
        }

        var adRequest = new AdRequest();
        adRequest.Keywords.Add("unity-admob-sample");

        print("Loading banner Ad !!");
        bannerView.LoadAd(adRequest);//show the banner on the screen
    }
    void CreateBannerView()
    {

        if (bannerView != null)
        {
            DestroyBannerAd();
        }
        bannerView = new BannerView(bannerId, AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Bottom);
    }
    void ListenToBannerEvents()
    {
        bannerView.OnBannerAdLoaded += () =>
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Banner view loaded an ad with response : "
                + bannerView.GetResponseInfo());
        };
        // Raised when an ad fails to load into the banner view.
        bannerView.OnBannerAdLoadFailed += (LoadAdError error) =>
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.LogError("Banner view failed to load an ad with error : "
                + error);
        };
        // Raised when the ad is estimated to have earned money.
        bannerView.OnAdPaid += (AdValue adValue) =>
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Banner view paid {0} {1}." +
                adValue.Value +
                adValue.CurrencyCode);
        };
        // Raised when an impression is recorded for an ad.
        bannerView.OnAdImpressionRecorded += () =>
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Banner view recorded an impression.");
        };
        // Raised when a click is recorded for an ad.
        bannerView.OnAdClicked += () =>
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Banner view was clicked.");
        };
        // Raised when an ad opened full screen content.
        bannerView.OnAdFullScreenContentOpened += () =>
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Banner view full screen content opened.");
        };
        // Raised when the ad closed full screen content.
        bannerView.OnAdFullScreenContentClosed += () =>
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Banner view full screen content closed.");
        };
    }
    public void DestroyBannerAd()
    {

        if (bannerView != null)
        {
            print("Destroying banner Ad");
            bannerView.Destroy();
            bannerView = null;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Interstitial

    public void LoadInterstitialAd()
    {

        if (interstitialAd != null)
        {
            interstitialAd.Destroy();
            interstitialAd = null;
        }
        var adRequest = new AdRequest();
        adRequest.Keywords.Add("unity-admob-sample");

        InterstitialAd.Load(interId, adRequest, (InterstitialAd ad, LoadAdError error) =>
        {
            if (error != null || ad == null)
            {
                print("Interstitial ad failed to load" + error);
                return;
            }

            print("Interstitial ad loaded !!" + ad.GetResponseInfo());

            interstitialAd = ad;
            InterstitialEvent(interstitialAd);
        });

    }
    public void ShowInterstitialAd()
    {
        if (interstitialAd != null && interstitialAd.CanShowAd())
        {
            interstitialAd.Show();
        }

        else
        {
            print("Intersititial ad not ready!!");
        }


    }

    public void InterstitialEvent(InterstitialAd ad)
    {
        // Raised when the ad is estimated to have earned money.
        ad.OnAdPaid += (AdValue adValue) =>
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Interstitial ad paid {0} {1}." +
                adValue.Value +
                adValue.CurrencyCode);
        };
        // Raised when an impression is recorded for an ad.
        ad.OnAdImpressionRecorded += () =>
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Interstitial ad recorded an impression.");
        };
        // Raised when a click is recorded for an ad.
        ad.OnAdClicked += () =>
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Interstitial ad was clicked.");
        };
        // Raised when an ad opened full screen content.
        ad.OnAdFullScreenContentOpened += () =>
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Interstitial ad full screen content opened.");
        };
        // Raised when the ad closed full screen content.
        ad.OnAdFullScreenContentClosed += () =>
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Interstitial ad full screen content closed.");
        };
        // Raised when the ad failed to open full screen content.
        ad.OnAdFullScreenContentFailed += (AdError error) =>
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.LogError("Interstitial ad failed to open full screen content " +
                           "with error : " + error);
        };
    }


    #endregion

    private void ResetCubeOrientation(GameObject cube)
    {
        // Reset the rotation to align the faces correctly
        cube.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, 0f);
    }

    public void Restart()
    {
        // MenuBTnsFX.Play();
        // SceneManager.LoadScene("SampleScene");

        MenuBTnsFX.Play();
        // Get the currently active scene
        Scene currentScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
        // Reload the current scene
        SceneManager.LoadScene(currentScene.name);
    }


    public void QuitButton1()
    {
        MenuBTnsFX.Play();
        StartCoroutine(LoadMainMenuWithDelay());
    }

    private IEnumerator LoadMainMenuWithDelay()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(.5f);
        SceneManager.LoadScene("MainMenu");
    }



    #region Rewarded

    public void LoadRewardedAd()
    {

        if (rewardedAd != null)
        {
            rewardedAd.Destroy();
            rewardedAd = null;
        }
        var adRequest = new AdRequest();
        adRequest.Keywords.Add("unity-admob-sample");

        RewardedAd.Load(rewardedId, adRequest, (RewardedAd ad, LoadAdError error) =>
        {
            if (error != null || ad == null)
            {
                print("Rewarded failed to load" + error);
                return;
            }

            print("Rewarded ad loaded !!");
            rewardedAd = ad;
            RewardedAdEvents(rewardedAd);
        });
    }
    public void ShowRewardedAd()
    {

        if (rewardedAd != null && rewardedAd.CanShowAd())
        {
            rewardedAd.Show((Reward reward) =>
            {
                print("Give reward to player !!");

                //GrantCoins(25);
                PlayerMovement.numbertOfCoins += 25; // Add 3 coins
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("NumbertOfCoins", PlayerMovement.numbertOfCoins);

            });
        }
        else
        {
            print("Rewarded ad not ready");
        }
    }
    public void RewardedAdEvents(RewardedAd ad)
    {
        // Raised when the ad is estimated to have earned money.
        ad.OnAdPaid += (AdValue adValue) =>
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Rewarded ad paid {0} {1}." +
                adValue.Value +
                adValue.CurrencyCode);
        };
        // Raised when an impression is recorded for an ad.
        ad.OnAdImpressionRecorded += () =>
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Rewarded ad recorded an impression.");
        };
        // Raised when a click is recorded for an ad.
        ad.OnAdClicked += () =>
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Rewarded ad was clicked.");
        };
        // Raised when an ad opened full screen content.
        ad.OnAdFullScreenContentOpened += () =>
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Rewarded ad full screen content opened.");
        };
        // Raised when the ad closed full screen content.
        ad.OnAdFullScreenContentClosed += () =>
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Rewarded ad full screen content closed.");
        };
        // Raised when the ad failed to open full screen content.
        ad.OnAdFullScreenContentFailed += (AdError error) =>
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.LogError("Rewarded ad failed to open full screen content " +
                           "with error : " + error);
        };
    }

    #endregion


   
    #region extra 

    void GrantCoins(int coins)
     {
         int crrCoins = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("totalCoins");
         crrCoins += coins;
         PlayerPrefs.SetInt("totalCoins", crrCoins);

         ShowCoins();
     }
     void ShowCoins()
     {
         totalCoinsTxt.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("totalCoins").ToString();
     }

    #endregion

}
```

I have read that maybe google takes time to show the ads .
but needs many devices send request for this ads , I have 7 friends , plating the game from yesterday, but no ads